# php -How to download video from download url

Tags: php

I've a download youtube scrip, after many changes I get to a point where I get a direct link to video, something like this :

```
http://r12---sn-4g57km7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?dur=265.868&pl=21&sver=3&mt=1444909527&ms=pm&source=youtube&sparams=dur,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&mv=s&itag=22&signature=A1D19A4DB1134E4ADF3CCBE8DDD7F5B01AB995B4.C0790F1AB331B4C290E83C292F064F67B811C17E&mm=35&mn=sn-4g57km7s&upn=qNbx8hdMDaU&nh=EAY&id=o-AAR67WMXg6mE9K6QpXf981YZf0B51_Jz_kEGYVHT9hdz&mime=video/mp4&expire=1444936669&ipbits=0&fexp=9408710,9414764,9414929,9416126,9417259,9417707,9418162,9418203,9418400,9418802,9418907,9418997,9421584,9421945,9422338,9422428,9422587,9422900&ratebypass=yes&ip=144.76.168.167&lmt=1444877662206720&key=yt6&signature=
```

when I enter the url in browser , it opens the video a plays it .

I tried this code but I get a file with the size of 0 as the result :

```
$download_video_file = file_put_contents("file", fopen($url, 'x'));
```

How can I download and save video from youtube and save it in my webhost ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download Videos from youtube is a complex issue...
Basically, youtube will generate a key when you access the video page, that key is **only** valid for the **ip** of the device accessing the page. 
Check the url you've posted for a variable called `ip` , it has the value `144.76.168.167`, this means that you'll **only be able to download the video from that ip**.

As I said, it's complex and you may want to take a look at https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ . It's opensource video downloader that [supports 700+ sites](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) including youtube and it's updated frequently by a huge community.

---

**[youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)**

> youtube-dl is a small command-line program to download videos from
>   YouTube.com and a few more sites. It requires the Python interpreter
>   (2.6, 2.7, or 3.2+), and it is not platform specific. We also provide
>   a Windows executable that includes Python. youtube-dl should work in
>   your Unix box, in Windows or in Mac OS X. It is released to the public
>   domain, which means you can modify it, redistribute it or use it
>   however you like.